# Connect two networks from different internet connection

Tags: networking

Is it possible con connect 2 different networks from 2 different internet connection (one is ADSL, the other one is 4g). The are both in the same office and each one have its own router.

Comment: Sure. But exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a printer and a nas on the first network, and I want users on second network to use this resources

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Just interconnect those two routers together and set static routes from each network to another. Your networks need to use different subnet (ie. 10.10.0.0/24 and 10.10.10.0/24). It will looks like this:

```
NET 1                             NET 2
-----                             -----
  |                                 |
------                            ------
| R1 |---Interconnect with LAN----| R2 |
------                            ------
| | | |                           | | | |
 LAN 1                             LAN 2
```

Comment: There will be probably problem with broadcasting, so you might need to setup printers, shared folders and so on manually.

Comment: by using this solution, will I use both internet connection or just one?

Comment: LAN1 will use NET1 and LAN2 will use LAN2. You will route just packets where target is in different packets, default route will stay same.